# creating a swap state hook that switches singular value on each click inside a state map?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a switch hook that simply have to change (one value) from a to c each time a function is called , meaning that if (a) is true on next click a will be (false) and b will be (true),only one true value at time but in order from a-c (circle), I am kind of confused whether integrating those three values is even good idea rather than making a separate state for each of them any idea how to tackle this?

```js
const [type, setType] = useState < {
  a: boolean;b: boolean;c: boolean
} > ({
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false
});


const swapType = () => {
  // get the current ture
  const getTrue = (obj: typeof setType, value: boolean) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).find((key) => obj[key] === value);
  };

  const copyObj = { ...type
  };
  for (let type in copyObj) {
    // Turn of the true !
    if (type === getTrue(type, true)) {
      copyObj[type] = false;
    }
    // Turn on following value only 
  }
  
  setType(copyObj);
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tuple of Boolean values (`[boolean, boolean, boolean]` in TypeScript) to do this.

```js
const swapType = (values: [boolean, boolean, boolean]): [boolean, boolean, boolean] => {
  values.every(val => !val) ? 
    values = [true, false, false] : 
    values[values.length - 1] ? 
      values = [false, false, false] : 
      values.unshift(values.pop());
  return values;
};
console.log(swapType([false, false, false]));
console.log(swapType([true, false, false]));
console.log(swapType([false, true, false]));
console.log(swapType([false, false, true]));
```

Comment: I added my current code using a for in loop and getting the current truthy value, might ring a bell..

Comment: I don't want to over complicate things but the issue here is I don't want to use 10 ifs as well smart compact approach.

Comment: the problem with your answer maybe I didn't specify it the right way is the default state is always false for all 3 values and on first click the first get updated to true, then false, true then false false true then back to original tripe false.

Comment: I added code for the case that you have all false. And now I saw the edit... Hold on.

Comment: Okay, nested ternaries make my eye twitch, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this using some if statements or a switch if this is all you are looking for. I am not sure if you want after c click to go back to triple false or return to a is true. You may need to adjust that code.

```
const swapType = (t)=>{
     if(t.a){
      setSetType({ a: false, b: true, c: false });
      return
     }
     if(t.b){
      setSetType({ a: false, b: false, c: true });
      return
     }
     if(t.c){
      setSetType({ a: true, b: false, c: false });
      return
     }
     setSetType({ a: true, b: false, c: false });
    }
```